# Небольшое регулярное выражение для pattern html

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть выражение: [А-Яа-яЁё\s]+$
Оно разрешает ввод любых кириллических букв и пробелов. Нужно к этому добавить ещё разрешение символов, таких как кавычки, точки, тире, запятые, цифры и т.д. 
Или может просто есть способ запретить латиницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запретить латиницу (основную) (и хотя бы 1 символ должен быть введен):

```
^[^a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)